# The space $\mathrm{Diff}_0(M)$ of all diffeomorphisms of $(M,g)$ in the same component as the identity

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

There is a symbol in the book *Geometric Relativity* by Dan A. Lee that confuses me.

> We will fix a specific submanifold $\Sigma^m\subseteq M^n$, and take $\mathcal{M}$ to be $\mathrm{Diff}_0(M)$, the space of all diffeomorphisms of $M$ in the same component as the identity. By pushing forward $\Sigma$ via diffeomorphism, this space will parameterize all of the submanifolds of $M$ that are isotopic to $\Sigma$ (indeed, this is the definition of *isotopic*). Of course, this parameterization introduces a huge amount of redundancy, but these redundancies will not cause problems for us. Even without the formalism of infinite-dimensional manifolds, we can still think intuitively about what the "tangent space" of $\mathrm{Diff}_0(M)$ at the identity should be: the space of smooth vector fields $C^\infty(TM)$. Explicitly, if one considers a smooth path $\Phi:(−\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathrm{Diff}_0(M)$ such that $\Phi_0$ is the identity, then we can define a vector field $X(p) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0} \Phi_t(p)$ for all $p\in M$. More generally, we can
> define $X_t(\Phi_t(p)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_t(p)$ so that $X_0 = X$. We abbreviate this by writing $X_t = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_t$. We often refer to the family $\Phi_t$ as a *one-parameter family of deformations* and $X_t$ as its *first-order deformation vector field*.
>
> Fix a compact submanifold $\Sigma$ of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with
> induced metric $h$ and induced volume measure $d\mu_\Sigma = d\mu_h$. Define $\Sigma_t =\Phi_t(\Sigma)$, where $\Phi_t$ is as described above. Our first goal is to compute the linearization of the volume functional at $\Sigma$ in the direction of $X$, also called the *first variation of volume with respect to the first-order deformation* $X$, which is just the quantity $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \mu(\Sigma_t)$.

The symbol $M$ should denote a Riemannian manifold. I was wondering the exact meaning of $\mathrm{Diff}_0(M)$. What are those diffeomorphisms of $M$ in the same component as the identity? What does the component mean? And what does it mean to be isotopic? Is it related to algebraic geometry? Is there an introductory book for people without knowledge of algebra and algebraic geometry?

Thank you.

Comment: No algebraic geometry whatsoever. This is the smooth category. This notation is more or less standard. An isotopy is a homotopy through diffeomorphisms.

Comment: In the very brief context of this quote, this is really differential topology, not so much differential geometry nor riemannian geometry. The symbol $M$ represents a smooth manifold, not a Riemannian manifold. So you should really pick up a differential topology textbook. In a relativity textbook, eventually $M$ might be a Lorentzian manifold; but not in the context of this quote.

Comment: Thank you all. I grabbed the DiffTop book by Hirsch. Hopefully, I can find something useful in this book.